# Google Maps API - Next page access problem

Tags: php, google-maps

I can't access the second page via access token.

```
$url = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$location&radius=$radius&type=$text_id&key=MY_API_KEY");
$url_json = json_decode($url, true);
echo $next_page_token = $url_json['next_page_token'];
```

When I'm displaying the variable, I get the right token :

```
echo $next_page_url = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=$next_page_token&key=MY_API_KEY");
```

When I'm displaying the next page variable I get response "status" : "`INVALID_REQUEST`".
But when I'm inserting the key that I got through `echo` in code like this :

```
echo $next_page_url = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=CrQCIwEAAAU1n0N9y_JzLi_HoFt_I7AoWHrNbRLfWXXHzSY4wE2pSDCtwSm3OJlVXb5nR_&key=MY_API_KEY");
```

I get the correct response.
What I'm doint wrong? Help plz.

Answer (score 0):

Send the request with the query params for the next page also.

```
$next_page_url = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$location&radius=$radius&type=$text_id&pagetoken=$next_page_token&key=MY_API_KEY");
```

**If your making 2 consequent requests than make the interval of 2 or 3 seconds between requests using sleep**

Comment: INVALID_REQUEST generally indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is missing.

Comment: still problem is the same. In place search google documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) at the end of the page is example and it is said about 2 parameters  (pagetoken and key). I think pagetoken contains info about query, and inserting pagetoken in url works fine

Comment: If your making 2 consequent requests than make the interval of 2 or 3 seconds between requests using sleep.